# How to calculate age in Adobe Flex from Date of Birth

Tags: apache-flex, date

I have read some threads about this already but I don't understand the code, so i'll ask a question that works specifically with the data I already have. My database has a user's date of birth in the following format:
`yyyy-mm-dd`

This field is pulled from the database using a php service, then populating a datagrid. I'm using an ItemRenderer to customise the columns. I would like to take my DOB which is accessed by `{data.dob}` and then work out the age in years. Do I have to split my result into days/months/years first, then calculate? or can I just do it from the DOB I get back? Also I've seen examples that use the date `01/01/1970` but I don't understand how that works.

Any correct answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use date Arithmetic.  Just subtract the current date from the `data.dob`.  I would use this [DateUtils](http://flexdateutils.riaforge.org/) class.

Here is a [sample](http://flexoop.com/wp-content/uploads/FlexDateUtilsDemo/FlexDateUtilsDemo.html).  Just use choose DateDiff, then choose the birth date as your first date and today's date as the second date.  Get the answer in years, and you'll have the person's age.

Comment: Thankyou for the response but I should really do this myself instead of using a tool that somebody has already created. Is there a function in flex for subtracting one date from another? I'm trying to do this manually but cannot figure it out.

Comment: @user1077544 I'm not sure I'm understanding your rationale.  You want me to provide you with code to subtract two dates from each other, but do not want to use a library someone built for that purpose?  I would download that library, and review the code inside to figure out how it works.  Read this too as it may help: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f10.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f0a

Comment: As much as I appreciate you providing me with a reasonable solution, I'm doing a university project so i'm a little reluctant to use other people's code. Plus, I'm a newbie so I'd like to learn how to do some of these functions manually.

Comment: @user1077544 I hope you understand the contradiction you're presenting.  The concept is "CurrentDate - BirthDate" and that should give you a number; which you can then convert into years.  Is that all you're after?

Comment: Yes, that's all i'm after. Don't worry though I already have some working code that will do this. I shall mark your answer as correct though because it was for most people.

Comment: I don't have enough room to paste it here, but I can link you to another question of mine where I came across a problem once I had the age working.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492259/adobe-flex-itemrenderer-making-calculations/10496418