# Adobe Flex ItemRenderer: Making Calculations

Tags: apache-flex, date, adobe, itemrenderer

I have a database including a user's Date of Birth, but I want to display their age. I have a function which calculates the age but I cannot use it in the ItemRenderer and I don't know why. I don't think it will work if I use this code outside of the ItemRenderer. The DOB is accessed by `{data.dob}`.

Here's my code:

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="age" headerText="Age" width="80">
                    <s:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                <fx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                        // Retrieving the user's DOB
                                        var dateStr:String = "{data.dob}";
                                        //Splitting the DOB up to make it compatible with Flex
                                        var parts:Array = dateStr.split("-");

                                        if(parts == null || parts.length != 3)
                                        {
                                            Alert.show("There is an error retrieving the birthday.");
                                        }

                                        var dobDay:* = parts[2];
                                        var dobMonth:* = parts[1] - 1;
                                        var dobYear:* = parts[0];

                                        var userDOB : Date = new Date(dobYear, dobMonth, dobDay);
                                        var today : Date = new Date();

                                        var diff : Date = new Date();
                                        diff.setTime( today.getTime() - userDOB.getTime() );

                                        var userAge : int = diff.getFullYear() - 1970;
                                    ]]>
                                </fx:Script>
                                <s:Label id="ageLbl" text="userAge" />
                            </s:GridItemRenderer>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </s:itemRenderer>
                </s:GridColumn>`
```

At first I was getting a #1084 error for `var dateStr:String = {data.dob};` so I changed it to `var dateStr:String = "{data.dob}";` and the errors migrated to `1120: Access of Undefined property Alert`. I also had the same error for: `diff, parts, today, userAge, userDOB`.
Any ideas here? Like I said the code works when outside of the ItemRenderer, using just one DOB.

Comment: Try using like this `var dateStr:String = data.dob;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:DataGrid x="71" y="58" width="490" height="264" requestedRowCount="4">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField1" headerText="Column 1"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField2" headerText="Column 2"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="dob" headerText="Age" width="80">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <fx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    import mx.controls.Alert;

                                    override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {

                                        if(data!=null)
                                        {
                                            trace(data.dob);

                                            // Retrieving the user's DOB
                                            var dateStr:String = data.dob;
                                            //Splitting the DOB up to make it compatible with Flex
                                            var parts:Array = dateStr.split("-") ;

                                            if(parts == null || parts.length != 3)
                                            {
                                                Alert.show("There is an error retrieving the birthday.");
                                            }

                                            var dobDay:* = parts[2];
                                            var dobMonth:* = parts[1] - 1;
                                            var dobYear:* = parts[0];

                                            var userDOB : Date = new Date(dobYear, dobMonth, dobDay);
                                            var today : Date = new Date();

                                            var diff : Date = new Date();
                                            diff.setTime( today.getTime() - userDOB.getTime() );

                                            var userAge : int = diff.getFullYear() - 1970;

                                            ageLbl.text = userAge.toString(); 
                                        }
                                    }

                                ]]>
                            </fx:Script>
                            <s:Label id="ageLbl" text="userAge"  top="7" left="9"/>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>

        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
    <s:ArrayList>
        <fx:Object dataField1="data1" dataField2="data1" dob="1990-05-25"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object dataField1="data2" dataField2="data2" dob="1981-02-15"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object dataField1="data3" dataField2="data3" dob="1956-05-7"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object dataField1="data4" dataField2="data4" dob="1994-08-25"></fx:Object>
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: This worked fine; thankyou. What does `override public function prepare (hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void` mean? I understand now why you need to import the mx controls again, but not what the function does, or what `trace(data.dob)` does. I have marked your answer as correct though.

Comment: You can override the prepare() method to make any final modifications to the display, such as modifying its visual characteristics or attaching event handlers. trace traces data.dob so you can see with what DOB data itemRenderer is working, or what is in dateStr. I recommend you to read more about itemRenderers, start at: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-7ff3.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using an inline item renderer. Think of an inline renderer the same way you would an item renderer in an external file. You will need to re-import mx.controls.Alert in order to use it. Additionally, if you want to call your main application variables from inside the itemRenderer, you need to make them public variables in your main app.